# Erlang ODBC for mySQL error with param_query stored procedure call

Tags: mysql, erlang, odbc

I'm getting a reproducible error when using the Erlang/OTP ODBC driver and mySQL. The error is received only when using odbc:param_query() to call a stored procedure with IN variables. The error occurs only on a consecutive param_query call.

The error is: {error,"[MySQL][ODBC 5.2(a) Driver][mysqld-5.6.37-log]Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now SQLSTATE IS: HY000"}

mySQL documentation says the error is caused when using C code mysql_store_result() and not following it up by mysql_free_result(). I believe this is either a problem with the ODBC driver on Erlang side or me not using the param_query properly.

The simple solution I found is not to use param_query or use a sql_query before each param_query I use.

Full example:

---

SQL:

```
DROP PROCEDURE if exists test_stored_procedure;

delimiter |

CREATE PROCEDURE `test_stored_procedure`(IN n INT)
    BEGIN   

    SELECT 1; 

    END
| delimiter ;
```

---

Erlang:

```
-module(odbc_test).
-compile(export_all).

connect() ->
{ok, Conn} = odbc:connect("DSN=myodbc", []),
Conn.

do_param_query(Conn, N) ->
odbc:param_query(Conn, "Call test_stored_procedure(?);", [{sql_integer, [N]}]).

do_sql_query(Conn, N) ->
odbc:sql_query(Conn, "Call test_stored_procedure("++ integer_to_list(N)++");").
```

---

Test:

```
96> odbc:start().
ok
97> Conn = odbc_test:connect().      
<0.237.0>
98> odbc_test:do_param_query(Conn,3).
{selected,["1"],[{"1"}]}
99> odbc_test:do_param_query(Conn,3).
{error,"[MySQL][ODBC 5.2(a) Driver][mysqld-5.6.37-log]Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now SQLSTATE IS: HY000"}
100> odbc_test:do_param_query(Conn,3).
{error,"[MySQL][ODBC 5.2(a) Driver][mysqld-5.6.37-log]Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now SQLSTATE IS: HY000"}
101> odbc_test:do_sql_query(Conn,3).  
[{selected,["1"],[{"1"}]},{updated,0}]
102> odbc_test:do_param_query(Conn,3).
{selected,["1"],[{"1"}]}
103> odbc_test:do_param_query(Conn,3).
{error,"[MySQL][ODBC 5.2(a) Driver][mysqld-5.6.37-log]Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now SQLSTATE IS: HY000"}
```

---

Please advise if you know what is causing the error.

Comment: Just an update, I have switched to using mysql native driver, mysql/otp. It works fine and has good documentation. https://github.com/mysql-otp/mysql-otp